# "client_id rejected" when attempting to use OpenID in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

As per the title, tapping on "Login using another OpenID" gives the error;

> Error description: "client_id rejected"

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, so it's not a one-off issue. Logging in with SE seems to work fine, though. I'd test the other methods if I had them.

Comment: Same issue here. Whenever the app opens the web view in an attempt to show the OpenID login page, it says *client_id rejected*. I then can go on logging in normally inside the web view, but I’m stuck in that web view then until I press Cancel or kill the app. The app ends up never using those credentials I have entered inside the web view.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.3.2 which is currently in Apple's review queue.  I passed the wrong parameter when building the URL so `client_id` was the wrong value.